# Get visible text on webpage given html nodes

Tags: go

I have some webpages and I would like to get only the text that is visible to a user. Currently I'm checking for text by doing the following:

```
n *html.Node

if n.Type == html.TextNode{
    print
}
```

The problem is I'm getting CSS code thrown in with my text, is there a way to only get the text? i.e.

```
<h1> I want to get this text and all others like it </h1>
```

Comment: Is there a library that you are using here?

Comment: @matt.s just ` "golang.org/x/net/html"`, if you count that. Everything else is in the standard lib.

Comment: could you give us a minimal working example ?

Answer (score 0):

With [GOQuery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery) - this is really easy.

```
doc, err := goquery.NewDocument("http://yoursite.com")
doc2.Find("h1").Each(func(i int, s *goquery.Selection) {
your_text,_ := s.Text()
}
```

Good luck!